# Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation, Invalid type: OpportunityLineItemSchedule

Tags: deployment

Unable to deploy package due to following error

Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class : Invalid type: OpportunityLineItemSchedule

Answer (score 1):

If one of the related classes got changed specially the methods, properties, arguments or return types then compiler make the dependent class as invalid.

You need to compile all the dependent classes. or otherwise, you can Compile All classes clicking on below link

[image]

Comment: Hi Santanu, Thank you for quick answer. However this issue is during deploying through DX. Compilation error is due to class which was dependent on fields of product(HasRevenueSchedule) which is made available only after configuring product settings in Product.setting-meta.xml file. Enabling this option resolved the issue